# Compare file text with argvc

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv

i am trying to read characters from a file (done) and count the number of times an argument from command line is displayed. When i`m running the code from below i get the following error in my terminal : " In file included from Fisier.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2) "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c, nr = 0;
    char filename[30];
    char ch;
    char *ch2;
    strcpy(ch2, argv[2]);

    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) { 
        do {
            ch = fgetc(file);
            if (feof(file))
                break;
            char *pChar = malloc(sizeof(ch));
            strcpy(pChar[0], ch);   
            if (strcmp(ch2, pChar[0]))
                nr++;   
        } while(1);

        fclose(file);
    }
    printf("%d", nr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pChar[0]`is of type char but `strcmp` expects type const char*. maybe you meant to pass `pChar` instead?

Comment: i`ve tried that before, this is the result : " /usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
"

Comment: a) always check `argc` and b) you have a memory leak from the `malloc` as you continually overwriting the pointer, c) you allocated only 1 byte of memory to copy a (supposed intention) string into.

Comment: It the second command line argument a single letter or a string?

Comment: it`s a single letter

Comment: Yes i was already wondering about that bit as `strcpy` also expects a char* and you are passing a char there as well. Probably should be `pChar` instead of `pChar[0]` there instead as well

Comment: @seleciii44: yet another dubious use of `do {} while`.  It would be clearer to write `for (;;) { ... }` as one would not need to read the whole body to get the infinite loop semantics.  As a matter of fact, this one should be written `while  ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) { ... }` assuming `int c;` of course.

Comment: Little difference, the errors / warnings i get don`t have anything to do with the do while block... if i replace strcmp with printf("%c", ch) it will display all the characters from file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program has several problems:

- you use string functions where you should just use characters directly.
- you use `feof()` to test for end of file, it is better to read file bytes into an `int` and compare with `EOF`.
- you copy `argv[1]` into a 30 byte buffer, command line arguments can be longer than 29 bytes.  Just use it directly.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c, search, nr = 0;
    FILE *file;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("usage: %s file character\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // set search as the character to count.
    //  it must be cast as unsigned char because getc(file) returns
    //  unsigned char values which may be different from char values
    //  if char is signed and the file contains non ASCII contents.
    search = (unsigned char)(*argv[2]);

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file) { 
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (c == search)
                nr++;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    printf("%d\n", nr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked, i tried something like that but my "search" variable was not of type int. Thanks for your help!